# ошибка sqlite3.OperationalError: near "": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

```
print(cursor.execute("SELECT like FROM users WHERE id {}".format(ctx.author.id)).fetchone()[0])
```

вот код на что получаю ошибку sqlite3.OperationalError: near "514814879845187587": syntax error

id получаю именно автора

Comment: Потому что нужно `id = {}`. Иначе вы получаете результат: `... WHERE id 123` и бд не понимает чего вы хотите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что не указано сравнение в условии WHERE. Вместо "id {}" должно быть "id = {}" или "id IN {}" в зависимости от значения ctx.author.id.

Comment: А лучше чтобы было `?`: `print(cursor.execute("SELECT like FROM users WHERE id = ?", (ctx.author.id,)).fetchone()[0])` :)

Comment: да,  было бы лучше(